# Ajuda com loop wordpress para gerar api json

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Ola bom dia gostaria de uma forca aqui nesse codigo:

`'Object'=> get_the_nome da imagem que esta no destaque()`

`'Categoria' =>get_the_nome da categoria`

segue o codigo completo :

```
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'publish');

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$array = array();

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    global $data;
    $array[] = array(

        'Object'=> 'aqui apenas o nome da imagem destacada',
        'Titulo' => get_the_title(),
        'Descricao' => get_the_content(),
        'Categoria' => 'aqui o nome da categoria',
    );

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($array);
exit();
```

Comment: Você deveria explicar melhor a questão. Além disso, você que alguém faça o código para você? Esse é um site sobre dúvidas técnicas, não para as pessoas resolverem seu problema. Em outras palavras, você tem que mostrar algum esforço em resolver o problema.

Comment: O rapaz todo mundo coloca seus códigos aqui e duvidas e é isso que estou fazendo mais ja consegui resolver abraço ai pra você tambem ! pra quem tem a duvida tambem segue o codigo que resolveu: $filename = basename ( get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) )

Comment: Colocar o código está correto. Pedir ajuda também. Mas é preciso mostrar algum esforço. De qualquer forma o wordpress.org é um bom lugar para buscar ajuda sobre a API do WP.

Comment: Já que vc já achou a resposta. Você pode responder sua própria questão e ajudar outras pessoas ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para o nome da imagem destacada da para fazer várias coisas, até mesmo pegar o título ou o `alt` dela.

Para título:

```php
get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() )
```

Para o atributo `alt`:

```php
get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true )
```

Já da categoria é simples de recuperar utilizando `get_the_category()`, entretanto é importante prestar atenção que esta função retorna um array, pois cada post pode ter infinitas categorias.

Comment: Obrigado Cláudio sanches resolvido a questão !

Comment: @HemersonPrestes podes marcar a resposta como aceite também...